# Narrow confidence interval for variance

Tags: confidence-interval, variance, chi-squared-test, standard-deviation

When we have an estimate of the variance $s^2$ obtained from $n$ observations, $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$, we can calculate a 95% confidence interval of the true variance

$$\left( \frac{(n-1)s^2}{\chi^2_{\alpha/2}}, \frac{(n-1)s^2}{\chi^2_{1-\alpha/2}} \right)$$

I want to get narrower confidence interval.

The best thing to do is to increase $n$, or we may use larger $\alpha$.

Are there any other available methods?

Any idea is appreciated.

Comment: while retaining the (unstated but implied) assumption of iid normality?

Comment: Do you have a particular problem in mind here? Information on the structure of your data may help in answering your question. For instance, a density plot would help. Otherwise, there is no other ways of getting a narrower confidence interval.

Comment: Also it seems that in your question you want $\alpha$ = 0.05.

Comment: @AaronDefazio This is very general question, so there is no exemplary data.

Comment: @Glen_b No assumptions here. I wonder if narrower CI are available if the data have specific distributions. The data may not be iid

Comment: @Michael Chernick No. alpha=0.05 is not required.

Comment: Your question is based on a mistaken premise (made explicit in the comments) -- it is only the case that the formula you give is a $1-\alpha$ interval for the variance if the original distribution sampled from is iid normal.